# WebDriver registering a callback on found

Tags: webdriver

When I search for an element like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("myId")).isDisplayed();
```

I want to run some code if the element is found (using the found WebElement I will scroll it to the middle of the viewport).  I want to do this for all calls to findElement() without having to manually duplicate the code every time I call it.

Is there some way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do such things by implementing [`WebDriverEventListener`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/WebDriverEventListener.html). Here is an example,

```
public class WebDriverListener implements WebDriverEventListener {
    private WebDriver webDriver;

    public WebDriverListener(WebDriver webDriver) {
        this.webDriver = webDriver;
    }

    public void afterFindBy(By findBy, WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {
        System.out.println("Found element now what??");
        //do whatever needs to be done after you find the element
    }
        ....
}
```

This is how to use

```
   @Test
    public void test() {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        EventFiringWebDriver efwd = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
        WebDriverListener eventListener = new WebDriverListener(driver);
        efwd.register(eventListener);
        efwd.get("http://www.google.com");
        WebElement element = efwd.findElement(By.name("q"));
        efwd.quit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by creating my own custom driver, I would rather a better method of doing this though.

```
public class CustomFirefoxDriver extends FirefoxDriver {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver#findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)
     */
    @Override
    public WebElement findElement(final By by) {
        WebElement element = super.findElement(by);

        //Automatically Scroll to the Element
        if (element != null) {
            Actions builder = new Actions(this);
            Actions action = builder.moveToElement(element, 0, 0);
            action.perform();
        }

        return element;
    }

}
```

Comment: You can achieve similar by creating wrapper methods for the webdriver methods.