# WebDriver tracking execution and logging results

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

We have a keyword driven framework on Selenium-RC. In this framework, keywords, identifiers and data are saved in an XML file and the frameworks will run AUT based on the keywords in XML file.

Currently we are changing this framework on webdriver. One area I am struggling is to log result after each step is being executed. Please suggest ways to perform monitoring execution like finding if the identifiers is available, checking if check box is selected, etc.

I have come across "WebDriverEventListener" and have been working if it is helping my requirement.

Please share your finding on how to log execution results.

Thank you!

Raja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely can use `WebDriverEventListener` and add custom log statements. I think that's a good idea. My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920878/webdriver-registering-a-callback-on-found/19933040#19933040) partly answers that question.

You can probably couple `WebDriverEventListener` with WebDriver internal logs. WebDriver provides you internal logs at various levels. To achieve this, you need to set `loggingPreferences` capabilities and once all of your tests are complete, you could retrieve logs and print/save them. For example,

```
LoggingPreferences loggingPreferences = new LoggingPreferences();
loggingPreferences.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
loggingPreferences.enable(LogType.CLIENT, Level.ALL);
loggingPreferences.enable(LogType.DRIVER, Level.ALL);
loggingPreferences.enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.ALL);
loggingPreferences.enable(LogType.PROFILER, Level.ALL);
loggingPreferences.enable(LogType.SERVER, Level.ALL);
DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, loggingPreferences);

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(desiredCapabilities);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
Logs logs = driver.manage().logs();
LogEntries logEntries = logs.get(LogType.DRIVER); //now pick the LOG type you want
for (LogEntry logEntry : logEntries) {
    System.out.println(logEntry.getMessage());
    //or save write it to log4j etc.
}
```

Comment: I have not tried yet Nilesh, working on another module. Surely i will get back to you on how it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use log4j. For example, add Maven dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Define logger:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class Log
{
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Log.class);

    public static void info(String message)
    {
        Log.info(message);
    }

    public static void warn(String message)
    {
        Log.warn(message);
    }

    public static void error(String message)
    {
        Log.error(message);
    }
}
```

Then you have to create logger object `static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("com.your.package");`

And now you can use it inside your test methods (or inside your pageobjects) like `logger.info("user clicked link to open login poup");`

Also you mast create config file for your logger

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <File name="LogFile" fileName="logs/${date:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}.log" immediateFlush="false" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.mycompany.openforbeta.utils.Log" level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="LogFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</configuration>
```

More information here http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/